# What will this B-tree look like?

Tags: b-tree

The B-tree is of order 4, meaning that a node can hold 4 pointers, and 3 keys.

The following is inserted: A G I Y

Since they can't all fit in one node, I know that the node will split.  So I know there's going to be a root node with 2 child nodes after these things are inserted, but I don't know exactly what they'll look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A
```

A is inserted

```
AG
```

G is inserted

```
AGI
```

I is inserted

```
  G
 / \
A   I
```

While inserting Y the node is full, split into 2 nodes and pass up the middle, G

```
  G
 / \
A   IY
```

Y is inserted

Answer (score 1):

Here's an animation of the operations:

[http://ysangkok.github.io/js-clrs-btree/btree.html#{"actions":[["initTree",{"keys":[]},2],["insert","A"],["insert","G"],["insert","I"],["insert","Y"]]}](http://ysangkok.github.io/js-clrs-btree/btree.html#%7B%22actions%22%3a%5B%5B%22initTree%22,%7B%22keys%22%3a%5B%5D%7D,2%5D,%5B%22insert%22,%22A%22%5D,%5B%22insert%22,%22G%22%5D,%5B%22insert%22,%22I%22%5D,%5B%22insert%22,%22Y%22%5D%5D%7D)

The second parameter to "initTree" is the order, but using another defintion. The maximum number of keys in this program is 2*order-1. So I set the order to 2 and it matches your example.